# Adding a SwiftUI view to a UIKit app gives me a `Missing argument for parameter 'font' in call` error

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios13

I have an existing UIKit application, using Storyboards. I want to add a new view using SwiftUI. My app is targeting iOS 13. The moment I add the SwiftUI view via `File -> New -> File... -> Swift UI View` I get a compiler error on the line with the default label `Text("Hello, World!")`. Do I need to update some configuration somewhere to enable Swift UI?

[image: Missing argument for parameter 'font' in call]

Comment: No you don't, are you sure you don't have `Text` class elsewhere in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have another type in your project named `Text`. You can differentiate it from the `Text` of SwiftUI by adding the module name before the type name:

```
var body: some View {
    SwiftUI.Text("Hello World!")
}
```